# Heroku - Something is already running on port 5000?

Tags: macos, heroku, stack, port, mern

First of all, I checked whole questions on stackoverflow and I can't find solution. When I try run my application by npm run dev, everything works. When I try to save something in VS Code (app crashed because something running on port 5000) then I have to change terminal, npx kill-port 5000 and npm run dev and over and over again.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const productRoutes = require("./routes/productRoutes");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");




const path = require("path");


if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { 
app.use(express.static('../client/build'));

app.get('*', (req,res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
} 
 
 
  
connectDB();
 
app.use(express.json());
 
app.get("/", (req, res) => { 
  res.json({ message: "API running..." });
});

app.use("/api/products", productRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon backend/server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "data:import": "node backend/seederScript",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install", 
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
    "develop": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run start --prefix client\"",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run start --prefix client\""
  },
```

When I try run heroku local, something running on that port already even though I killed the port

https://github.com/TomaszSygut/Shopping-cart

If someone know what's going on please help me. I already spent 2 days on that weird error

Comment: Can you post the heroku output/logs?

Comment: Those logs? sur.la.route?

Answer (score 0):

```
2021-06-23T12:12:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user thomassygut@gmail.com
2021-06-23T12:14:54.513779+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user thomassygut@gmail.com
2021-06-23T12:14:54.513779+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 9ceb0c19 by user thomassygut@gmail.com
2021-06-23T12:14:55.204758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-23T12:14:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-06-23T12:15:06.592623+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-06-23T12:15:09.222001+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-23T12:15:09.222019+00:00 app[web.1]: > mern-shoppingcart-redux@1.0.0 start /app
2021-06-23T12:15:09.222020+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently --kill-others-on-fail "npm run server" "npm run start --prefix client"
2021-06-23T12:15:09.222020+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-23T12:15:09.249330+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2021-06-23T12:15:09.252247+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-06-23T12:15:09.252540+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-06-23T12:15:09.252732+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-06-23T12:15:09.252908+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-06-23T12:15:09.253986+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern-shoppingcart-redux@1.0.0 start: `concurrently --kill-others-on-fail "npm run server" "npm run start --prefix client"`
2021-06-23T12:15:09.254100+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-06-23T12:15:09.254327+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-06-23T12:15:09.254441+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern-shoppingcart-redux@1.0.0 start script.
2021-06-23T12:15:09.254573+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-06-23T12:15:09.263627+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-23T12:15:09.263773+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-06-23T12:15:09.263872+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-06-23T12_15_09_255Z-debug.log
2021-06-23T12:15:09.344222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-23T12:15:09.410230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-23T12:15:09.414393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-23T12:15:23.748088+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-06-23T12:15:26.383257+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-23T12:15:26.383287+00:00 app[web.1]: > mern-shoppingcart-redux@1.0.0 start /app
2021-06-23T12:15:26.383288+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently --kill-others-on-fail "npm run server" "npm run start --prefix client"
2021-06-23T12:15:26.383289+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-23T12:15:26.388074+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2021-06-23T12:15:26.394007+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-06-23T12:15:26.394493+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-06-23T12:15:26.394934+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-06-23T12:15:26.395258+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-06-23T12:15:26.397033+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern-shoppingcart-redux@1.0.0 start: `concurrently --kill-others-on-fail "npm run server" "npm run start --prefix client"`
2021-06-23T12:15:26.397313+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-06-23T12:15:26.397658+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-06-23T12:15:26.397902+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern-shoppingcart-redux@1.0.0 start script.
2021-06-23T12:15:26.398179+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-06-23T12:15:26.407147+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-23T12:15:26.407449+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-06-23T12:15:26.407673+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-06-23T12_15_26_400Z-debug.log
2021-06-23T12:15:26.468310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-23T12:15:26.643298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-23T12:16:01.052036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mini-shopping-app-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=c0f9a708-ddb7-4923-b5cc-b1b15fb61bca fwd="83.14.122.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-23T12:16:01.542494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mini-shopping-app-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=f5e95ed2-5b89-4dbc-ac4c-0b3c582ae5d1 fwd="83.14.122.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-23T12:34:24.211883+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mini-shopping-app-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=36fe077b-9763-4056-86b7-228e9726f08a fwd="83.14.122.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-23T12:34:24.720272+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mini-shopping-app-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=ee3de3f0-fdd8-4978-9952-76b8f487c990 fwd="83.14.122.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: It looks like the failure is because the command "concurrently" is not found?